# Excel Interop - Cancel selection

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I'm copying and inserting rows in an Excel sheet, like so:

```
   while (rowsToAdd > 0)
   {
      // copy the existing row
      insertionCell.EntireRow.Copy(Type.Missing);

      // location of the new row
      Range newRow = insertionCell.EntireRow.get_Offset(1, 0).EntireRow;

      // insert the new row
      newRow.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, Type.Missing);

      rowsToAdd--;
   }
```

The problem I have is that sometimes, I'm left with a selection marquee around the row I originally copied.

Is there a way I can cancel the selection marquee (the way you'd normally do it with the Escape key?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA it's `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: It looks like it's an enum, not a bool. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241059(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: You're right that it's an enum.  It's a weird one where it's got enums but, in VBA at least, you can also just set it to FALSE.  I've done it many times.  It's interesting that you've decided that the documentation is wrong.

Comment: Maybe 'Confusing' is a better word. If I try to set it to false, I get a compiler error. To someone who did not know any better, it would look like an error in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
myExcelApplication.CutCopyMode = XlCutCopyMode.xlCopy;
```

seems to do the trick, though the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.cutcopymode.aspx) does not explain it very well, and seems to be wrong, since bools are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty old, but as I had some issue copying one row to another, and as I got the proper solution on my case, I'm now glad to share it, just in case it could fix your problem (thinking about copy rows instead of inserting one).

Here is the solution:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlSourceRow;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlNewRow;
xlSourceRow.Copy(xlNewRow);
```

Using this solution prevents from getting any selection in your MS-Excel file.