# How to disable cut,copy and paste option in excel using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have tried the code shown below to disable cut,copy and paste option in excel using c#, but still I'm able to copy and paste.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wks =   (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wkb.Sheets[1];

wks.Application.CutCopyMode = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCutCopyMode)0;
```

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I got the same issue, I fixed it with the code used there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826429/7991036

It fixed definitely the issue for me!