# Deselecting currently editing cell in c# interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have a test button in Excel Addin that looks like this

```
private async void TestBtn_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application curExcel =
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook curWorkbook =
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)curExcel.ActiveWorkbook;
    Excel.Worksheet workSheet = curWorkbook.Worksheets.Item[1] as Excel.Worksheet;


    Excel.Range line = (Excel.Range) workSheet.Rows[1];

    line.Insert();
}
```

It works fine except when I have a cell selected as editable - so when the cursor is flashing on one of the cells. So I need to be able to deselect the cells before I do the `line.Insert()` How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's pretty old, but have a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826429/7991036

It might fix your issue with alternative way (sometime it's nice to think out of the box).